# how to make form array nested in the same form array

Tags: angular7

i have form array name in a table it is repeat and i want plus row in any table in form array name and i have index of form control name

angular 7 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCqT9.png)

in html file : 
in description photo
in ts file :

```
patchValuestourguide( nationality , day_cost , no_days , no_person, cost_per_person, including) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({

        day_cost : ['']   

    });
}
addTourguideFeildValue(index) {

    console.log(index);

    const control = this.formTourguide.get('Tourguide') as FormArray;

    control.push(this.patchValuestourguide( ''));

    this.TourGuidefieldArray.push(this.newTourGuideAttribute);

    this.newTourGuideAttribute = [];

}
```

Comment: Can you improve your grammar?

Comment: i have form array name in a table it is repeat and i want plus row in any table in form array name 
and i have index of form control name